# Database from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Well, I have done this code before and it has worked, but this time it just wont work, please help me out here. I have searched the web for hours and tested many options, can't make it work. As you might have guessed I just want everything from my database (written in ssms) to be passed to the view, without errors. I get many different errors, the latest error is:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FE.Blog]'.

The controller:

```
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {

        var q = from p in dbBlog.Blog
                select p.Description;
        return View(q.ToList());
    }
```

The View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<FE.Blog>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @item.Description
        }
```

Comment: the problem is because you are sending only one column i.e. description which is a list of string from controller but view expects complete object of FE.Blog..just change query on controller side send all columns of Blog table and filter it on view ..

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting just one column `p.Description` which is `string` but your view expects Model to be `IEnumerable<FE.Blog>`.

So change your model in view if you need only on column:

```
 @model List<string>

 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
   @item
 }
```

Or if you want the view to bind with `IEnumerable<FE.Blog>`  then you have to the object in query instead of just selecting one property:

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
   var q = from p in dbBlog.Blog
           select p;
   return View(q.ToList());
 }
```

and in View:

```
@model IEnumerable<FE.Blog>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   @item.Description
}
```

Comment: My first soultion was your answer (I've tried about 100 combinations), and that didn't work. I tried it now again, and I got the result: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1". Usually I just type  "return View(dbBlog.Blog.ToList());" and use the IEnumerable in the view, that usually works.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem I think, it looks so.

The problem was that I had forgot the **"@model FE.Blog"** above another forms **using-statement** in another View. There are partials view all over the place, this explains the errors I've been collecting.

Regards